# How do I link the title column to the document in a document library SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Since our name column is garbage a lot of times we clean provide a godd file description on the Title field thus we want to be able to click on the Title field to open the doc not the Name field.  Any suggestions ?  I spent several hours researching and I find a lot on SP 2010 and how to do this for a list, but nothing for SP 2013 library.

Comment: Are you want to link document title to link document in document library or somewhere else?

Comment: In SharePoint 2010 that would have been a few clicks in SharePoint Designer 2010 to add the ECB (Edit Control Block) to any column in design view. But the wise people at Microsoft elected to remove design view in SharePoint Designer 2013, so unless you are an XSLT wizard, this is now impossible.

Comment: Look into JSLink, it provides a way to override any fields, you can build your own html anchor tag using the FileLeafRef and Title property.

Comment: DOM, its just for the document library.  I want to be able to click on the value found underneath the Title column to open the document....Aveenav...will this work ?  http://blog.jussipalo.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-linking-item-titles-to.html